# Can separate but identical arrays EVER be equal by reference

Tags: java, arrays

In java, if you have two arrays with identical contents, but they were separately constructed, `array1 == array2` will be false because equals does a reference check and their references are different. But is it guaranteed they'll always have different references? For example

```
public class TestArrayReferences {
    private static final String[] SENTINEL_ARRAY_1 = new String[0];
    private static final String[] SENTINEL_ARRAY_2 = new String[0];

    public static boolean testArrays() {
        return SENTINEL_ARRAY_1 == SENTINEL_ARRAY_2;
    }
}
```

If I call testArrays, I'm returned false, but is it guaranteed to always be false? Namely, is the JVM permitted to detect that SENTINEL_ARRAY_1 and SENTINEL_ARRAY_2 will always be identical and therefore have them reference the same array?

Comment: Use `java.util.Arrays` to compare arrays

Comment: `new` always means "new".

Comment: @ChrisMartin do you have a link to any official specs (or reputable sources) that guarantees new is always a new object?

Comment: @VishnuModi see the JLS cite in response to your comment on my answer. Chapter 10 of the JLS addresses arrays generally, see especially 10.3

Comment: [JLS 10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3) is kind of vague, but if we read "An array is created by an array creation expression or an array initializer" very literally, "created" implies a new reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they were both created by allocating new arrays and not by assignment, no they cannot be reference identical.

Arrays are not interned, as Strings are, so creating a new array creates a new item in memory. This is why you can create several new arrays of int, of the same length, and add items to one without adding them to the other as well.

EDIT: notice also that Strings are immutable, which is why they can be interned and not run into problems. If Strings were mutable, interning wouldn't work:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
s1.setchar(0, 'J'); // fictional method to change one char of a String
```

If this method existed, and Strings were interned, then s2 would also be set to "Jello", unless some sort of dis-interning were done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My concern was that either the JVM is permitted to detect that this array is never modified, or that an empty array is immutable, and make an exception. You wouldn't happen to have a link that new is guaranteed to always be new would you?

Comment: From the JLS: An array creation expression creates an object that is a new array whose elements are of the type specified by the PrimitiveType or ClassOrInterfaceType.  (15.10.1)

Comment: If you want to see a guarantee in the implementation, you'd have to go spelunking at grepcode. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an array with new keyword, a block of memory is allocated in the heap and your reference points to it. Until or unless other reference points to that same memory space in heap, the result of double equal operator will be false.

In your case two different memory blocks are allocated to two different references so , the result will be false and will always be false until the above criteria is met.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array, your are 'assigning' a fixed number addresses in your memory, to be used by that array, its length is irrelevant.

```
String[] arr1; // Gets allocated, for example, in memory address 0x04383833
String[] arr2; // Gets allocated, for example, in memory address 0x012A3A03
```

0x04383833 will never be equal (==) to 0x012A3A03

so Yes, to your question, they will always return false if compared with double equal.

this is exactly the reason why we use the .equals method when comparing strings and not double equals, Strings ARE arrays of characters.